# Can't update table 'transaction' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have problem with my trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER complete_transation
AFTER INSERT ON transaction
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DECLARE id_trans INT;
DECLARE id_stock INT;
DECLARE type_transaction BIT(1);
DECLARE id_match INT;

SET @id_trans = NEW.idTransaction;
SET @id_stock = NEW.stock_idStocks;
SET @type_transaction = NEW.type;

IF(@type_transaction = 1) THEN
    SET @id_match = (SELECT idTransaction FROM transaction WHERE stock_idStocks = @id_stock AND type = 0);
    UPDATE transaction SET status = 1 WHERE idTransaction = @id_match;
END IF;
IF(@type_transaction = 0) THEN
    SET @id_match = (SELECT idTransaction FROM transaction WHERE stock_idStocks = @id_stock AND type = 1);
    UPDATE transaction SET status = 1 WHERE idTransaction = @id_match;
END IF;



END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Is there any chance to change the other record in table where trigger was invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.
when trigger fires it may lock the table.